# Add a new line of text/function to an existing html file with JSFL

Tags: javascript, html, flash-cc, jsfl

I want to add some line of text/function to an existing html file. I can  read the file with `FLfile.read()`, and this is my code:

```
var pathCom=fl.getDocumentDOM().pathURI(); //get complete path

var pathWOFile=pathCom.substr(0,pathCom.lastIndexOf('/')); //get the path without file

var readFile=FLfile.read(pathWOFile+'/index.html'); //read the html file

alert(readFile);
```

and the structure of my html file is :

```
<html>
  <head>

     <script>
         //i want to add a new function on this line
     </script>

  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

i already even know there is a function called `FLfile.write()` to append text to the file, but the text always added in the last line of the structure. Now i want to add some text function to the line between the `<script>` tag, how can i doing that, sorry for my bad english and thanks for your response